# C++ HexChat SendMessage get Chat

Tags: c++, sendmessage

I have done something like this before in visual basic but it was a long time ago and it was for Wolfenstein ET. I know that I will have to use SendMessage or WM_GETTEXT so all I would need is the code the would constantly get the text from the chat window. Now hexchat is opensource but I do not know how to go about and get the ID that is needed to specify. I would rather not use a handle since I would have to recompile it every time. I know this is asking for a lot but I have been trying to figure this out for the past couple of days with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Oops also forgot to mention that since HexChat is open-source should we be able to use GetDlgItem()?

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FindHexChat()

{

HWND hwndNotepad = FindWindow(L"gdkWindowToplevel", NULL);

if (NULL != hwndNotepad)
{

    HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(hwndNotepad, NULL, L"Chat", NULL);

    if (NULL != hwndEdit)
    {
        int textLen = (int)SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);

        if (0 < textLen)
        {

            const int bufferSize = 1024;
            char textBuffer[bufferSize] = "";
            SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);

 << cout << textBuffer << endl;



}
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
 endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    FindHexChat();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does being open source have to do with using `GetDlgItem`? Note that there's `GetWindowText` and `GetWindowTextLength` as well.

Comment: Don't you get the `GetDlgItem` from the source? If not how do you get it? Also I looked at hexchat though spy++ and the only window named is the top level. Everything below that is `""` How would you go about this?

Comment: Well, `EnumChildWindows` will get them all. It really depends on how much unique information you have.

Comment: Ok well I ran some code and it returned all of the child windows but they look like handles. Am I going to have to test each one or? And if so how would I do that?

Comment: If each child window doesn't have some specific piece of information that can distinguish the one you need from the others and that you can recognize, then you're going to have to find the right control a worse way, as you said.

Comment: Hate to keep this going but lets say I enum the child windows then use sendmessage or wm_gettext to see if it has text and if it doesnt remove it and keep going. and if it does then keep it?

Comment: You'd have to take into account that a lot of the child windows will have text, and if their titles (note: not class names) show up as blank, getting the text won't work. I don't know what else to use in that case.

Comment: Well could I modify the source code and compile it to somehow make it easier?(getting late so I may not answer until morning)

Comment: You *could*, I suppose, but do you really want to? At that point, I'd even take relative position. I really can't give any solid methods based on the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of the window you are looking for can be determined from the source code or with Spy++.  Every child window HWND is returned by EnumChildWindows. For each of those HWNDs you can call GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_ID) to get that child window's ID. When it matches the target ID you have found the HWND that can be used with WM_GETTEXT to read the window's text.

Comment: If it can be determined by source then how would I find it it?: https://github.com/HexChat/hexchat I have searched through almost the whole thing and have not found anything that has stood out. If you could look and see i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Hmm... Well I wanted to add something that would help me find it but I cant find any forum online that has done something like this.